# UITableView footer view issue in iOS 10 due to autoresizingMask

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the following code for adding table footer view with a label.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 60)];
view.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
label.text = @"The End";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[view addSubview:label];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = view;
```

- It was working fine with iOS version less than iOS 10.
- Only on iOS 10 I footer view goes outside of the frame and is getting displayed only if we pull up the tableview out of its scrolling bounds.
- And on releasing the tableview again the footer view goes out of view.

Can anyone please let me know whats happening here in iOS 10, Do we need to change the approach shown above.

But I found that by removing the following line of code it works fine.

```
view.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
```

Could anyone explain why this happens ?

Comment: Did you solve this?